# ¿Cómo puedo quitar la "T" de la fecha en Java?

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

estoy desarrollando un programa en el que debes seleccionar una fecha, una hora y otros datos y después subirlo a una BD MySQL.

He creado un "método" para seleccionar la fecha y la hora por separado, y juntarlas después en una sola (utilizo interficie gráfica, pero el problema no está ahí). La cosa es que cuando lo junto y lo transformo en un LocalDateTime para subirlo a la BD (cuyas columnas son DATETIME)

Al subirlo me daba error de sintáxis, y he ido imprimiendo los valores de la fecha y la hora y he visto que todo estaba correcto, hasta que imprímia la fecha completa (fecha y hora juntas) y veía que en el momento de separar la fecha y la hora, lo separaba con una "T". Este es el código:

```
dataSort=inputdatasortida.getValue();
System.out.println(dataSort);
String partsarribada[]=inputtimearribada.getText().split(":");
String partssortida[]=inputtimesort.getText().split(":");
for(int i = 0; i < partssortida.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(partssortida[i]);
}
DataentCompleta=dataEnt.atTime(Integer.parseInt(partsarribada[0]), Integer.parseInt(partsarribada[1]));
        
DataSortCompleta=dataSort.atTime(Integer.parseInt(partssortida[0]), Integer.parseInt(partssortida[1]));
System.out.println(DataSortCompleta);
Desc=inputpes.getText();
```

Y esta su respuesta:

```
2022-06-06
10
00
2022-06-06T10:00
2022-06-06T10:00
```

Cómo veís las partes por separado las imprime bien, pero en el momento de juntarlas añade una "T" en vez del espacio que aceptaría la BD.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para quitar esa T y sustituirla por un espacio?

Comment: No está demás mencionar que la _T_ es por el [estándar ISO-8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Fechas_y_horas_conjuntas).

Comment: Entonces, ¿cómo es que la BD no lo acepta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución sería.
Declaramos las siguientes variables para fecha y hora

```
LocalDate date= LocalDate.now();// 2022-06-06
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(10, 00, 00);//hh:mm:ss
```

La forma de unir estas 2 variables en un LocalDateTime es:

```
LocalDateTime datetime= LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
```

Ahora habiendo declarado nuestras variables Connection `cn` y PrepareStatement `pst`, para poder realizar un insert desde java (LocalDateTime) hacia la base de datos (datetime) haremos lo siguiente:

```
String sqlInsert="insert into FechaHora (fechaHora) values (?)";
try{
   cn.setAutoCommit(false);
   pst = cn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);
   pst.setObject(1,datetime);
   pst.executeUpdate(); 
   cn.commit();
}catch(SQLException e){
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que está usando la clase `LocalDateTime` para almacenar y manipular su fecha, puede usar `DateTimeFormatter` para personalizar cómo desea que su fecha se represente como una String.

Siga usando la forma de la base de datos para almacenar la fecha, pero cuando vaya a mostrarla/imprimirla, luego formatéelas de la manera deseada, ejemplo a continuación:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(ldt); //<- 2022-06-06T15:39:19.951
    
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    final String str = ldt.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(str); //<- 2022-06-06 15:43
}
```

Y puedes manipular el formato como quieras/necesites, solo tienes que modificar el patrón en `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");`

si quieres día-mes-año: `"dd-MM-yyyy"`

Si desea solo día y mes: `"dd-MM"`

si quieres todo, hasta los segundos: `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: Pero entonces le estaría pasando un String, y por la clase que tengo necesito que sea LocalDateTime. ¿Existe alguna otra manera que no cambie el tipo de dato?